# Is there an equivalent of tf.gradients function in tensorflow C or C++ API?

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-c++

I want to implement a tensorflows function [tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) in C or C++ API? Tensorflow C++ has the [worst documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc) in the world and C API aren't documented at all. Can you suggest if there is an implementation or which API parts should I use to develop this myself.

Comment: To do it yourself, you can just calculate the vector of partial derivatives. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative

Comment: @SimonGoater So there is not a chance to find out in the API? Because I need them to work on GPU. It is a part of the large program.

Answer (score 0):

The C functions that the python function `tf.gradients` calls on can be found in the following header file:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/gradients/grad_ops.h"
```

You can use `tensorflow::GradientTape` to initialize a tape which the can call on the `gradient` function to compute the gradient of a tensor `y` in respect to `x`.

Comment: Is there any example of using this? Because there is really nothing on the internet

Comment: Yeah, usually there's not much on how to use these internal functions online. My strategy which I would recommend is to trace the Python function which you want to use through the Python API in the code-base. I don't have the time to spell everything out for you. But you will take your intialized Tensors x and y, make shure they are `flat` and then use the `GradientTape` function `Compute`on them with a given comparison function which you give as an argument. You can also use the `watch` function to make some calculation to then compute the change after the permutations.

Comment: You can use the raw GradientTape function with the python API. The usage is very similar in the C++ API: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape